# Should you always compile with newtest library version?

Tags: android, compilation, dependencies, libraries

I'm releasing my application on the store and I'm wondering if I must always compile with the newtest version or it is ok to compile with lower versions. 
Im asking because I had some problem at the beginning when I was compiling with highest version and I've read on the documentation of android developing that you should always compile with newtest version

Print screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTurL.png

Answer (score 1):

Actually, It's up to you. But as regular library it has not only new features but also various improvements, optimisations and bug fixes. So I would say yes, you should always compile your project with the latest play-services library.